# Can a matrix be invertible but not diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

While reading a chapter on diagonalizable matrices, I found myself wondering:

> Can a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be invertible but not diagonalizable?

My quick Google search did not return a clear answer.

Comment: Yes. A $2\times2$ shear matrix is the simplest example, e.g. the matrix whose first row is $(1,1)$ and whose second row is $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 48):

After thinking about it some more, I realized that the answer is "Yes".

For example, consider the matrix

\begin{equation}
A = 
\left [
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right ].
\end{equation}

It has two linearly independent columns, and is thus invertible.

At the same time, it has only one eigenvector:

\begin{equation}
v = 
\left [
\begin{array}{c}
1  \\
0 
\end{array}
\right ].
\end{equation}

Since it doesn't have two linearly independent eigenvectors, it is not diagonalizable.

Comment: It is worth noting that there also exist diagonalizable matrices which aren't invertible, for example $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, so we have invertible does not imply diagonalizable and we have diagonalizable does not imply invertible.  There are matrices that are neither, that are both, or that are only one of either.

Comment: @JMoravitz it seems to me that $\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$ is the best example of a diagonalizable non-invertible matrix. Of course your example works too!

Comment: ...and to complete things: $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is neither diagonalizable nor invertible. Garrett: you might want to look up Jordan blocks.

Answer (score 16):

Geometric(-ish) answer. Take, in $\mathbb R^2$, a rotation of angle $0<\theta<2\pi$ with $\theta \neq \pi$. Then the associated matrix is invertible (the inverse being the rotation of $-\theta$) but is not diagonalisable, since no non-zero vector is mapped into a multiple of itself by a rotation of such angles.

Comment: It's worth noting that it is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$ though.